# limit involving harmonic function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^3 -\{0\}$. I know that $$\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{|x|} \cdot u(x)=k< \infty$$

I'm trying to show that $k=0$. I tried by contradiction, but I failed and I'm beginning to suspect that $k$ may be different from $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{|x|} \cdot u(x)=k< \infty$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}|x|u(x)=\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{|x|} \cdot \sqrt{|x|} \cdot u(x)=0 \cdot k=0$$

then $0$ is removable point. Let $v:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ harmonic extension of $u $ so:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{|x|} \cdot u(x)= \lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{|x|} \cdot v(x)=0  \cdot v(0)=0=k$$

Comment: What result are you using to see $0$ is a removable point.

Comment: Suppose $u$ is a harmonic function in $\Omega - \{x_0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n, n>2$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}|x-x_0|u(x)=0$  then $x_0$ is removable point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider

$$u(x)-P[u|_S](x) + \frac{\epsilon}{|x|},\,\,\text{for }0<|x|<1.$$

Here $P$ is the Poisson integral for the unit ball and $S$ is the unit sphere. This function is harmonic on $\{0<|x|<1\}$ with boundary values $\ge 0.$

Comment: This is a good hint. Why the downvote?

Comment: Sorry it was not intentional, I did not see that I had given dowvote. I can not undo it.